# How do I add api.ai support for a new language

Tags: android, github, internationalization, dialogflow-es, google-text-to-speech

Can volunteers develop support for more languages supported in Api.ai?

We want to add Hebrew support. We are developers and audio engineers. Is there a way to plug into the project (which is up on GitHub)?

Is this dependant on Google Text-to-Speech? And if so, the question passes on to Google Text-to-speech. Is there a way to externally plug into the project and add what's needed for another language's support?  If so where to start?

Comment: Did you found the way to use Hebrew in API.ai? I thought about using Google translate, from Hebrew to English and then to pass it to API.ai, but this approach doesn't look production ready.